# powerpoint, vba, generate a random number from a specific set

Tags: vba, powerpoint

VBA - how can i generate a random number within the specific set 3,5,7,9,11,13.
these numbers represent slide numbers (destinations) which the user will be taken to when a button is clicked.

Comment: You can do a random function between 2 and 13 and then check if the numbers are even, if they are then do not use that number. Also what would the purpose of this be?

Comment: The purpose of the requested code is to go to different starting slides each time a game is begun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: Modified to include a more comprehensive solution at request of OP**

Objective: Randomly select one of six possible slide numbers to display following the click of a button.

**Step 1: Code to randomize slide number selection**

Map the target values into an array. Note the number of elements in the resultant array - in this case, 6. Generate a random integer from 1 to 6, and use that value as an index into the array, returning the value at that index position.

Something like the following (untested)

```
function randomSlideNumber() as Integer

   Dim index 
   Dim targetValues(1 to 6) as Integer

   targetValues(1) = 3
   targetValues(2) = 5
   targetValues(3) = 7
   targetValues(4) = 9
   targetValues(5) = 11
   targetValues(6) = 13

   index = Int(6 * Rnd + 1)

   randomSlideNumber = targetValues(index)

end function
```

**Step 2: Add slides to a Powerpoint presentation up to the number desired in the random selector**

I'm assuming the OP already has at least 13 slides in his presentation :)

**Step 3: Add an additional slide to the presentation, and add a CommandButton to it**

1. With the new slide active in Powerpoint, click the 'Developer' tab.
2. Select a `CommandButton` from the Controls toolbar, and draw it onto the new slide.
   [image: VBA Controls w/CommandButton highlighted]
   [image: PowerPoint slide with VBA CommandButton]
3. Double-click the CommandButton. This should open the VBA editor with a stub Click event handler for the CommandButton, called `CommandButton1_Click()`.
   [image]
4. Modify the handler code as follows:

P

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide randomSlideNumber

End Sub
```

**Step 5: Start the slide show, using the slide with the new CommandButton as the starting point**

1. With the new slide active, select the "Slide Show" tab from the ribbon bar
2. Click "From Current Slide" from the "Start Slide Show" bar.

[image: Start Slide Show with new slide]

**Step 6: Click the CommandButton on the slide, and verify that the active slide changes to one of those returned by the `randomSlideNumber()` function**

Voila! :)

**Code Discussion**

**Note: This involves a little detail about the PowerPoint VBA object model.**

Clicking the CommandButton in the slide created in Step 3 fires the `CommandButtton1_Click()` event handler created in Step 4. The event handler then goes to the current `View` of the first `SlideShowWindow` object `SlideShowWindow(1).View`, and calls the `GotoSlide` method of the `View`. The `GotoSlide` method expects a *slide number* as a parameter, which is provided by the call to the 'randomSlideNumber' function defined earlier. That function should return one of 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, or 13.

That *should* do the trick. 
**Caveats: There is obviously no error handling in this code; its addition is left as an exercise. Further, this has *not* been extensively tested against the very latest version of Powerpoint, but did work in the test shell I created.**

Comment: thx, I would like to test this code but unable (lack the expertise) to assign it to a button.  Any chance you can make the code a subroutine pls?

Comment: Sub go_slide()
Function randomSlideNumber() As Integer

   Dim index
   Dim targetValues(1 To 6) As Integer

   targetValues(1) = 3
   targetValues(2) = 5
   targetValues(3) = 7
   targetValues(4) = 9
   targetValues(5) = 11
   targetValues(6) = 13

   index = Int(6 * Rnd + 1)

   randomSlideNumber = targetValues(index)
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.GotoSlide index
End Function
End Sub

Comment: Hi @puzznic sorry I hadn't been back here. I will be happy to expand on this for you but it will be a bit later today, okay?

Comment: thank you David, all help will be very much appreciated

Comment: @puzznic - Apologies for the delay in getting back to you!! I've modified the solution to incorporate as much help as I could infer you might need along with some screen shots and some detail on how to wire it all up. You may need to read up just a bit on the PowerPoint object model to understand some of it, but either way, I hope this is useful for you!

Comment: Thank you David.  I will test this as soon as I can and post results here

Comment: David, this code works like a dream, Voila indeed.  I just had to remove the word 'private' from the subroutine name to make it appear in the ppt macro list.  I am very very grateful for your help,   Art

Comment: Awesome, @puzznic! If you wouldn't mind checking this as the answer I'd be most appreciative!